# Python - Accept input from bash and send by query string

Tags: python, bash, http, stdin, ibeacon

I am new to Python and trying to my script to send the output of this command 'ibeacon_scan -b' to be sent to a web server by query string or any other efficient way to send data continuously. Here is what the output looks like for 'ibeacon_scan -b'

```
iBeacon Scan ...
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 4 -71 -69
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 6 2 -71 -63
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 4 -71 -69
3F234454-CFD-4A0FF-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 5 7 -71 -64
...keeps updating
```

I am piping the command to my Python script

```
ibeacon scan -b | stdin.py
```

Here is my code for the my script 'stdin.py'

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
import httplib
import urllib

for line in fileinput.input():
   urllib.urlencode({"UUID": {"Major":{"Minor":RSSI}}})
   headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-formurlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("67.205.14.22")
   conn.request("POST", "post.php", params, headers)
   response = conn.getrespone()
   print response.status, respone.reason
   data = respone.read()
   print data
   conn.close()
```

I'm getting these errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stdin.py", line 7, in <module>
    for line in fileinput.input():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 253, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 346, in readline
    self._buffer = self._file.readlines(self._bufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Is my script even getting the data correctly from the pipe? Is the formatting correct for the query string?

Comment: I think you may be interested in [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for Python, I usually use it to use bash in Python. But not sure if it's the best way to solve this

Comment: Is there a character Python can receive that will send the `KeyboardInterrupt` signal? That's supposed to be what `Ctrl+C` is for.

Comment: I used `Ctrl+C` to stop the program and it gave me those errors.

Comment: @ThomasHall that's exactly what those errors mean. It means "you stopped the program with `Ctrl+C`." That's what a `KeyboardInterrupt` is. Was your program broken in some other way before you tried to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

As @TheSoundDefense pointed, it must be some `KeyboardInterrupt` character in the ibeacon's output:

A fast check shows that piping in linux actually works:

```
>>> cat tmp.txt | python -c "import fileinput; print [line for line in fileinput.input()]"
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd\n']
```

Where `tmp.txt` contains 4 lines with `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have it pipe in? Because if not, you can do something like this all in your python script (thanks oliver13 for the idea):

```
popen = subprocess.Popen(["ibeacon scan -b"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
   urllib.urlencode({"UUID": {"Major":{"Minor":RSSI}}})
   headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-formurlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
   conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("67.205.14.22")
   conn.request("POST", "post.php", params, headers)
   response = conn.getrespone()
   print response.status, respone.reason
   data = respone.read()
   print data
   conn.close()
```